# Distributed custom model function for Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get my model that uses `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` with a custom model function to perform distributed training.

The [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) specifies that jobs (ps and/or worker) should be manually placed in the model using the `tf.device` function. However, this documentation refers to the old way of declaring the model, without the use of the `Estimator` class and model functions.

I found some [information](http://terrytangyuan.github.io/2016/06/09/scikit-flow-v09/#distributed-estimator) stating that the new `Estimator` "handles most of the complicated distributed logics of model training and evaluation". Does this mean that the various worker/ps jobs still need to be manually placed in the model? And if yes, is there any change in the way they should be declared from the code in the Tensorflow documentation (i.e. using `tf.device`)?

Comment: Estimator is a new addition to TF and seems to be a bit of of a work in process. I couldn't find examples of using it for distributed training, if you manage to get it working, you could update the answer here so that other people can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around a bit, I found [this code sample](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-do-time-series-prediction-using-rnns-and-tensorflow-and-cloud-ml-engine-2ad2eeb189e8) and was able to get distributed TF working with `Estimator` without having to manually place the various `tf.device` in the model function.